# Creating a empty hemisphere

Tags: objects

I'd like to create an empty hemisphere in blender eevee, so i.e. a bowl, but I have no idea how to do it. If anyone could help me I would be very thankful.

Comment: Shift A to create a UV Shere, go in front orthogonal view, switch to Edit mode, press Alt Z for transparency, press B to select the top half, X to delete the vertices, then select all and press Alt E to extrude along normals

Answer (score 3):

Add a sphere

Enter edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Select top vertex and select more <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> until you reach the part you want

Delete <kbd>X</kbd> vertices

[image]